# link to pdf not working on mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, pdf-generation

I have a basic html link to a pdf file on a page, when clicked is opens the pdf on PC but on mobile nothing happens when the link is clicked. I have

```
<a href="linktofile.pdf" target="_blank">Click to pdf</a>
```

Can someone help advise how do I make it work on mobile (andorid & ios) so that users can just click to download the pdf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using the full link like http://example.com/linktofile.pdf . If still you get a problem, then try checking with your friends phone. I've just now checked with my website, it's working with Chrome built-in browser. Also check for default PDF Viewer.

Comment: yup tested with full link. but not working too. nothing happened when its tapped on

Comment: Which browser do you use on android device? My phone came with in-built PDF Viewer, when i click on .pdf links, it opens in PDF Viewer then from menu i get Option to download. So try installing any PDF Viewer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try without target. I would use modal to view external files such as PDF, images, etc..

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the response.

I found the problem was not on the a href but rather on the css class. there was a class used causing the link un-clickable on mobile which made it not responding to any tap. once the class is removed everything worked fine.

sorry for my careless mistake.

Thank for all you time guys.